# Equivalent of ENDIAN_BE16() function for Ubunu

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, qnx, qnx-neutrino

What is the exact equivalent of the following function for Ubuntu?

http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.1/neutrino/lib_ref/e/endian_be16.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is:

```
#include <endian.h>

result_in_host_endianness = be16toh(my_big_endian_number)
```

See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/endian.3.html